# How to Prompt Before Send in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

I am using outlook 2010.

I would like to receive a popup after clicking on the send button. 
The Popup should say "Do you want to continue sending the mail?" and it should have two buttons on it

1. Ok( After clicking on it the mail should be sent)
2. Cancel( The mail should not go)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your VBA macro:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Just press ALT+F11 in Outlook, copy-paste the macro to **ThisOutlookSession** object and save it.